# Adding Multiple "Parents" in get_categories

Tags: customization, categories

I am using the below mentioned code to get top 5 child categories (by number of posts) from a Parent category. **The code works fine**, however I need to add more "Parent" categories so that I cant get total of Top 5 child categories from multiple parent categories.

```
Adding 'parent' => '599,588,590',  **Does not work.**
```

**The working code for single parent category.**

```
<?php
$args=array(
  'orderby' => 'count',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'parent' => '599',
  'number' => '5'
  );
$categories=get_categories($args);
  foreach($categories as $category) {
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.' (' . $category->count .')</a></li>';
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get it in one call.

Instead, make multiple calls, then sort the data  each call gave you into a single array, and take the top 5 in the new list.

e.g.

```
$args=array(
  'orderby' => 'count',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'parent' => '599',
  'number' => '5'
  );
$categories=get_categories($args);

$args2=array(
  'orderby' => 'count',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'parent' => '588',
  'number' => '5'
  );
$categories2=get_categories($args2);

// etc...
```

Finally you would create a new array that you will use to display the top 5 categories. You will fill this array by searching through the 5 category arrays you have just acquired, and picking out the categories with the highest count..

Think of each array as a top 10, and you're compiling a new top 10 given 5 lists. You'd find the highest category in all the 5 lists, then the next highest, and once you've got 5 items you'd stop and write down your final list.

Comment: I'm not sure if I explained the question right or you understood what I meant. I need to get top 5 "Child Categories" by number of posts from Multiple Parents. I do not want a "child category" to be listed under multiple parents.

Comment: I've ammended my answer

Comment: Yeh, that is exactly my problem, I understand that it needs multiple call but unsure of how that can be achieved. Can't we simply create an array of parents also?

Comment: No, it would give the same result as passing in comma separated list.

Comment: Thanx, What would be the last part of the code where all array are stored and top 5 categories are calculated? I have no clue!

Comment: Imagine doing it with lists of inventory in your head, write it down then rewrite your 'pseudo code' as actual code. To simply put it in my answer would be insulting your intelligence ( if someone asks you to put the heaviest cans in a bag given 5 bags  and a 6th empty one, Im sure you'd have a clue, why would code be any different? )